# How to solve the Dirac Equation and find its eigenfunctions?

Tags: dirac-equation, spinors, dirac-matrices

Imagine you want to solve the Dirac equation:
$$
(i\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu - m )\psi=0 \\
$$
Where $\gamma^\mu$ are the $4 \times 4$ gamma matrices, and $\psi$ is a 4 component spinor.
$$
\psi = \begin{pmatrix}
\psi_1 \\
\psi_2 \\
\psi_3 \\
\psi_4 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
When you trying to solve this differential equation, the derivatives of the different spinor components would be mixed by the matrices, and appear in all equations. You will finally get, a system of 4 equations, all of which depends on all the 4 spinor components.

My question is, how would you even solve this? It is possible to arrive to a differential equation that depends, only, on one function at a time?

Comment: The analytic solutions I'm aware of are the hydrogen atom https://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node501.html and the plane wave solutions in free space http://www.nhn.ou.edu/~milton/aqft/lect4.pdf

Comment: You solve it as a usual system of partial differential equations (i.e. by guessing an answer).

Answer (score 1):

Solving the Dirac equation for a free particle
(i.e. without any external fields)
$$(i\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu - m )\psi=0 \\$$
which you have written down,
is actually not that hard.
Searching for ["Dirac equation free particle"](https://www.google.de/search?q=dirac+equation+free+particle) will give many hits.

You begin with the approach where the wave spinor field $\psi(\mathbf{x},t)$
is the product of a constant spinor $u$ and a plane wave
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\psi_1(\mathbf{x},t) \\
\psi_2(\mathbf{x},t) \\
\psi_3(\mathbf{x},t) \\
\psi_4(\mathbf{x},t)
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
u_1 \\ u_2 \\ u_3 \\ u_4
\end{pmatrix}
e^{i(\mathbf{p}\mathbf{x}-Et)}$$
and $\mathbf{p}$ and $E$ are still unknown constants
(the momentum and energy of the particle).
This will lead you to the constraint
$$E^2=\mathbf{p}^2+m^2$$
(which of course is the relativistic energy-momentum relation)
and 3 algebraic relations between the 4 numbers $u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4$.
So you don't have differential equations anymore.

Comment: What if you want to add a potential?

Comment: @ÁlvaroRodrigo Then this simple approach doesn't work anymore.

Comment: And what is the correct approach?